# File Name checking

Tags: java, arrays, search, filter, filenames

I was making a class that searches for missing files out of a sequence of them (IE: test-1.txt test-2.txt test-4.txt) out of curiosity and when I finally got it to work and I realized I had no idea how to keep checking for missing files after it finds one missing. The problem is that the counter I use to ask for what number in the sequence of files wont work after it finds a missing file because it's permanently off at that point. What I thought might work would be asking what is on the end of the current aFile.getName() and assigning it as an int to i regardless of the fact that it might not be a number(what goes into the actual counter that is a string and is put onto what is checked for). Appearently that doesn't work and gives me:

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "t"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at TestingClass5.main(TestingClass5.java:43)
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TestFileSequence {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 0;
  //Start Dialogue
  String userDefinedFilePath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input directory"); //File dir
  String userDefinedFileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input file name"); //File extension
  String userDefinedFileType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input group extension"); //File name
  //Start Filter
  FilenameFilter userDefinedFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
   public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
    if (name.endsWith(userDefinedFileType)) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   }
  };
  //Start Array
  File dir = new File(userDefinedFilePath);
  File[] files = dir.listFiles(userDefinedFilter);
  //Check for files matching description
  if (files.length == 0) {
   System.out.println("The directory doesn't contains any matching files. Please check the directory, extension, and name specified below for accuracy.");
   System.out.println("Directory Specified: " + userDefinedFilePath);
   System.out.println("Extension Specified: " + userDefinedFileType);
   System.out.println("Group Name Specified: " + userDefinedFileName);
  } else {
   //Check files for gaps in sequence
   for (File aFile: files) {
    String counter = Integer.toString(i);
    String check = userDefinedFileName + "-" + counter + userDefinedFileType;
    if (aFile.getName().equals(check)) {
     System.out.println("File: " + aFile.getName() + " is present.");
     i++;
    } else {
     System.out.println("Checked for :" + check);
     System.out.println("What was found: " + aFile.getName());
     String resetCounter = aFile.getName().substring(aFile.getName().length() - 1); //Assigns string resetCounter to the last character in the current aFile.getName() regardless if it isn't a number 
     int resetLength = Integer.parseInt(resetCounter);
     i = resetLength;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: check what `resetCounter ` returns `String resetCounter = aFile.getName().substring(aFile.getName().length() - 1);`

Comment: Ahh right. Completely forgot that the extension was part of what is returned and not just the name of the file. Can I just ask the file extension length and subtract that instead of just one then? Is there a way to even ask the length of only the extension? The only one I can think of is building another for loop that goes through the file name backwards and then looks for the very first period to get a length.

Comment: Completely forgot that I have the string UserDefinedFileType as something that tells me what the extension is. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the number at the end of the file name

```
String resetCounter = aFile.getName().substring(aFile.getName().length() - 1); 
//Assigns string resetCounter to the last character in the current aFile.getName() regardless if it isn't a number
```

for a file called `test-1.txt` so the last letter is `t` not `1`

You could get the digit before the last `.` or after the first one or find any number in the file name instead. I suspect you want the number e.g. `test-10.txt` should be `10` not `0`

You could do

```
String resetCounter = aFile.getName().replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
```

This just keeps the digits.